# JSONException: java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, jsonexception

I know this question has been asked a number of times but I didn't find any relative answer of my question.

I am trying to read json data from asset folder, but I'm getting following exception while getting

I searched number of stuffs but didn't help. Please give me any reference or hint.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
   String searchedTerm = jsonObject.getString(TAG_SEARCHEDTERM);
   JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
```

instead of

```
  JSONObject searchedTerm = jsonObject.getJSONObject(TAG_SEARCHEDTERM);
  JSONArray results = searchedTerm.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
```

because `TAG_SEARCHEDTERM` is key-value pair instead of `JSONObject` and you are trying to cast a String value to `JsonObject`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to get the **Dish Name** where you are getting exception.
You can get the dish name shown below...

```
String searchedTerm = jsonObject.getString(TAG_SEARCHEDTERM);
```

Using this

```
JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
```

you will get the `"results"` JSONArray as shown in your json file.

and you can iterate through it using for loop.